# Return character parsing KML file

Tags: java, android, dom, kml

I have two problems parsing a KML file.
I'm using DocumentBuilder to do it. This is an example part I want to parse:

```
<Placemark>
 <description>&lt;div align=center&gt;&lt;img src=some_image.jpg  width=300 height=220/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;SOME IMAGE&lt;/div&gt;</description>
 <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
 <ExtendedData>
   <Data name="Numero">
     <Value>00032</Value>
   </Data>
   <Data name="Nombre">
     <Value>GTA ALONSO MARTINEZ</Value>
   </Data>
 </ExtendedData>
 <Point>
   <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
   <coordinates>-3.69556116887887,40.4276170711932,10 </coordinates>
 </Point>
</Placemark>
```

The first thing is that when I want to get the childs of "Placemark", I get some return characters "\n" between tags. For example

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");
String node = nodeList.item(0).getTextContent(); // node = "\n"
String node2 = nodeList.item(1).getTextContent(); // node = [content of <description>]
```

The other issue is if DocumentBuilder can convert html characters (< and >) into (< and >) to get into this tags and parse it properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a KML library like http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/

Specifically this is nearly always the answer to generating or parsing KML, especially if you are unfamiliar with XML parsing, character sets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options that can be configured in `DocumentBuilderFactory`, such as coalescing (i.e. expand CDATA elements into text nodes), ignoring comments, etc.

In your case if you just want to dump the XML content without space content (tabs, \n, space, etc.) in plain text without those inter-element "\n" you should pass `true` to `setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace()` method of `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work. I still have the \n spaces